# Did Ben Ish Chai and RSh"R Hirsch Communicate with Each Other?

Tags: history, samson-raphael-hirsch, ben-ish-chai

It occurred to me that Ben Ish Chai (Hakham Yossef Hayyim) from Baghdad and Rabbi Shimshon Raphael Hirsch were contemporaries, and that they held similar positions in their respective communities. Did the two rabbis ever communicate? Did they share correspondence, or comment on the same halakhic or communal questions?

Comment: A fascinating question, but not sure it would be on topic here.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  I must be missing something (see upvotes), but I don't really know why is it fascinating to randomly pick two distant rabbanim. Did they have a common field of expertise that they could discuss?

Comment: Unlikely. At that point of time Iraq and Germany were two different worlds. Which Iraqi and European rabbi had any correspondence if they didn't move to Eretz Yisroel first

Comment: @Schmerel I was told that the Ben ish chai had numerous correspondence with European rabbis.

Comment: I saw a letter once in a museum between rabbanim in Iraq and England trying to arrange a get between a couple that had separated.  I don't remember the era. @schmerel